# NCurses in Docker Container

Tags: docker, tor, python-curses

I currently have a TOR relay set up in a Docker container for quick deployment online. Everything is working well and ARM (a TOR monitoring application) is installed and ready to be used.

When I execute a bash shell in the container to run ARM (a Python app that uses NCurses), ARM throws the following error:

*curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal*

I start up the container, everything starts up fine, then I exec a shell as follows:

*docker exec -t -i container_id /bin/bash*

Once I have the bash shell, I run the ARM application which results in the error above.

Googling the issue indicated that the TERM environmental variable might be incorrect (*echo $TERM* comes back with *dumb*). The *t* flag in Docker is supposed to be setting up a TTY.

I assume others have come across this issue with Docker containers, but I'm at a loss regarding how to solve the issue. Googling doesn't come up with anything Docker specific.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix this on an ongoing basis.  But once in the terminal session typing

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Should do it.

Comment: This worked perfectly! As reference, the correct way to do this in a Docker File is:

ENV TERM xterm

Comment: I had to use `xterm-256color` to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Docker documentation says it will automatically assign `TERM` ( could be a version issue ); but if you add `-e TERM` to the command line then the value of TERM will match the value in the parent shell.

Your new command would look like this:

```
docker exec -ti -e TERM container_id /bin/bash
```

Now you will find that `TERM` inside the container will match `TERM` outside the container (which is probably what you want anyway since the emulator is the same).