# ncurses app running in a docker container exits early

Tags: docker, rust, ncurses

I have an ncurses [app](https://github.com/overclockworked64/hstr-rs/) written in Rust. I wanted to make a Docker image so that people could install the application more efficiently. I wrote a [simple Dockerfile](https://github.com/overclockworked64/hstr-rs/blob/master/Dockerfile), specifying the full-blown Rust base image. I built my image, ran it inside a container, and everything worked flawlessly. However, since the resulting image was way too big (1GB+), I figured I should give the Rust alpine image a shot. I managed to build my image (after having to add ncurses-dev and musl-dev with apk), but now my app exits early - I can see no output. When I try to look at the logs, nothing gets printed out.

Here's the Dockerfile I wrote that uses the alpine image:

```
FROM rust:1.61.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN apk add ncurses-dev
RUN apk add musl-dev
RUN cargo install --path .

CMD ["hstr-rs"]
```

Why does my app exit early when I use the alpine image?

Comment: Probably not specific to Rust but ncurses and Docker in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769124/ncurses-in-docker-container

Comment: (I'd rather download and run a single static binary than run a Docker container, especially if I need to `sudo docker run -u $(id -u) -v "$HOME:/files" --rm -it your-name/hstr` to run it instead of just `./hstr-rs`.)

Comment: @MarcusIlgner I've already seen that question, and I tried passing `TERM` but to no avail.